# Should we have a close reason for technical support questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

We've gotten several questions that have been technical support type questions:

- https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/695/cant-be-established-connection-with-internet-whats-up
- https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/689/question-on-how-many-rewrites-on-a-specific-ssd
- https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/585/is-there-mercury-in-a-mouse
- https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/asus-x501u-cant-play-video-above-1080p

Current wording on these also suggest they are technical support vs. hardware recommendation/information leading to recommendation:

- https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/688/can-i-exchange-a-native-asus-x551m-hard-drive-and-a-toshiba-canvio-connect-ii-ex

  > Would the two fit in each others' respective slots? They look like they have different formats.
- [HDMI switches - how are they supposed to work?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/620/hdmi-switches-how-are-they-supposed-to-work)

  > Is this behaviour normal, or have I just bought junk?

I am proposing, when we can, that we have a close reason specific for this type of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest the following wording for such a close reason

> **Technical support request**
>
> Questions asking about **troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware** are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations. We are here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task.

Comment: This is a pretty good wording, although I'm not a fan of using "we" in close reasons.

Comment: There are plenty of characters remaining.  How's "Hardware Recommendations  is here..." sound?

Comment: "Questions asking about hardware troubleshooting or technical support..." would be clearer I think.

Comment: I'd be tempted to suggest SU as an alternate site, as many OT close reasons do.

Comment: That didn't get a good reception,  @JourneymanGeek: http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/124/add-specific-close-reason-for-superuser-content

Comment: ahh, fine then ;p

Comment: I don't think “questions that will lead to a specific recommendation” means anything to people who haven't followed the meta debates from the private beta. And “recommendations for hardware” is pretty vague. I strongly recommend changing the last sentence to something that makes sense to someone who isn't intimately familiar with the site. The phrases “pre-purchase recommendation” and “recommend hardware for a specific goal” come to mind but I'm not in a sentence-crafting mood right now.

Comment: I just realized I hadn't marked this answer as a community wiki. Everyone is free to wordsmith the close reason wording.

Comment: I like the new wording, but is there a way we can better explain 'pre-purchase'? I'm not sure someone new here that hasn't followed all the Meta discussion would know what it means.

Comment: @Undo, I'm sure there is a concise way...but I'm not coming up with one off hand.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the *"closed as a..."* line in close reasons. I think it's better to just explain the closure, without introducing it.